# How do I turn on/off the beep in the terminal in Linux?

Tags: linux, bell

In linux `echo -e '\a'` is one way you can alert the user with a beep.

- But if it isn't working how to enable or diagnose it?
- And if it is working how's the best way to quiet it.

(This was asked [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/26405/how-do-i-turn-off-the-beep-in-the-terminal-in-linux) but that question was closed.)

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to disable.  Getting the beep to work can be harder.

Here are some things to look at.

- If using GNOME Terminal, Menu> Edit> Profile preferences> Terminal bell check box.
- If using GNOME ALSA Mixer under the tab for your sound driver> Beep column> check or uncheck the Mute box and set volume. (You might first have to show the Beep column with Menu> Edit> Sound Card Properties.)

For me (a notebook running Debian Stretch) these don't seem to matter:

---

- set prefer-visible-bell on
- set prefer-visible-bell off

---

- sudo modprobe -r pcspkr
- sudo modprobe pcspkr

Comment: This answer is wrong BECAUSE: The TERMINAL bell doesn't use ALSA or any other "sound system" as it doesn't use the system speakers. It's just a type of buzzer attached to the motherboard. And THAT is what the question actually asks to turn off.

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues turning off the bell in xterm, to fully eliminate the sound on my system, Fedora 30, I replaced the in use alarm sound in `/usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts` by an .ogg file with no sound.